# Error while using k-means

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using data from http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/New_Home_Page/data.html and am trying to cluster the 60th column (Net Income).  However, I get the following error

```
datacol<-b[3:3000,60:60]
datacol<-datacol[!is.na(datacol)]
datacol

Error in kmeans(datacol, centers = 35) : 
  more cluster centers than distinct data points.
In addition: Warning message:
In kmeans(datacol, centers = 35) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

What could be going wrong?

Comment: Could you make your example reproducible, i.e. provide a small data sample that reproduces the issue.

Comment: How many data points remain **after remving NaN values**? `datacol` might be empty after the second line!

Answer (score 0):

You should tell us which data set in that page you used (it seems to me there are lots).

Did you check the data? chances are that the error message is accurate and the data does not have >=35 DISTINCT data points.